# Adding an accept header in Angular 5

Tags: angular, github, http-headers

How do I add an accept header in Angular 5?

I am using GitHub API to show Projects in a GitHub repository. The [GitHub API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/projects/) says that to use it, I must provide a custom media type in the Accept header.

Here is my code. It currently returns the Unsupported Media Type Error.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { GitIdInfo, GitRepo, GitProject} from './github-id';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

const githubAPI = 'https://api.github.com/';

@Injectable()
export class GitIdInfoService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  GetGitProj(login, Repo: String): Observable<GitProject[]>{
    const userProject = githubAPI + 'repos/';
    return(this.http.get<GitProject[]>(userProject + login + '/' + Repo + '/projects'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider reading the documentation?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score -2):

Here is how I would set in the simplest format

```
GetGitProj(login, Repo: String): Observable<GitProject[]>{
    const userProject = githubAPI + 'repos/';
    let header = new Headers({'content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: header});
    return(this.http.get<GitProject[]>(userProject + login + '/' + Repo + '/projects', options));
  }
```

Here's bit more complicated but handy to use one

```
GetGitProj(login, Repo: String): Observable<GitProject[]>{
    const userProject = githubAPI + 'repos/';
    let header: Args[] = [
        {id: "Authorization", val: "ahjsbdhaskajsd"},
        {id: "Accept", val: "value"}
    ];

    return(this.http.get<GitProject[]>(userProject + login + '/' + Repo + '/projects', this.addHeader(header)));
  }


/***
   * Generates default headers I.E. #content-Type and append any optional headers provided
   * @param {Args[]} args an array of Args[KEY, Value]
   * @returns {Headers}
   */
  private addHeader(args: Args[]): Headers {
    let headers: Headers = new Headers();
    let a: Args = new Args;
    a.id = "content-Type";
    a.val = "application/json";
    headers.append(a.id, a.val);
    if (args == null) return headers;
    args.forEach(a => {
      headers.append(a.id, a.val);
    });
    return headers;
  }
```

This is using the new style:

```
GetGitProj(login, Repo: String): Observable<GitProject[]>{
    const userProject = githubAPI + 'repos/';
    return(this.http.get<GitProject[]>(userProject + login + '/' + Repo + '/projects', {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('content-Type', 'value')}));
  }
```

Comment: nope, you are mixing the old Http API with the HttpClient API

Comment: My web app was done a year ago and back then that's how we did it. But I've added the newer style example.

Comment: Yellow quote blocks are supposed to be for quotes. Not just your answer content.